# Issue with setting and opening fragments in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am having a issue, as my app is crashing instead of opening the fragments. I have a ListActivity, that takes you to another activity; and in that other activity, there are two fragments. The ListActivity is expecting a result from one of the fragments.

My code was working prior to adding the fragments! However the fragments are no longer showing up and the app closes...does anyone possibly know what my issue could be? And any advice on how to take this issue? I sincerely appreciate all and any help, thank you! My code is below.

The ListActivity.java:

```
public class LyricList extends ListActivity {
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;
private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private LyricsDbAdapter mDbHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lyriclist);
    mDbHelper = new LyricsDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

private void fillData() {
    Cursor lyricsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllLyrics();
    startManagingCursor(lyricsCursor);
    String[] from = new String[]{LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
    SimpleCursorAdapter lyrics = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.lyrics_row, lyricsCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(lyrics);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            createLyric();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            mDbHelper.deleteLyric(info.id);
            fillData();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void createLyric() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    fillData();
}
}
```

The other activity class that should be opening via the listActivity:

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab one = actionBar.newTab().setText("Lyric Editor");
    Tab two = actionBar.newTab().setText("Loops");

    one.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(new LyricEditorFragment()));
    two.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(new LoopsFragment()));

    actionBar.addTab(one);
    actionBar.addTab(two);
}
public class MyTabListener implements TabListener{
    Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabListener(Fragment f){
        fragment = f;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.replace(R.id.frame1, fragment);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
    }
```

Not sure if you want to see the fragment class, but here is this just incase:

```
public class LyricEditorFragment extends Fragment {
private EditText mTitleText;
private EditText mBodyText;
private Long mRowId;
private LyricsDbAdapter mDbHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new LyricsDbAdapter(getActivity());
    mDbHelper.open();

    mTitleText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.title);
    mBodyText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.body);
    Button confirmButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.confirm);

    mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
        (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                : null;
    }

    populateFields();

    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            getActivity().finish();
        }

    });
}

private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor lyric = mDbHelper.fetchLyric(mRowId);
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(lyric);
        mTitleText.setText(lyric.getString(
                lyric.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
        mBodyText.setText(lyric.getString(
                lyric.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    populateFields();
}

private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();

    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mDbHelper.createLyric(title, body);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateLyric(mRowId, title, body);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lyriceditor, container, false);
    return view;
}

    }
```

[image: crashlog]

Comment: Crash log from logcat if you may..

Comment: took a picture of it, is this okay? Is it too small, or do you need to see the rest of it?

Comment: @webhoodlum what is line 35 of the LyricEditorFragment

Comment: line 35 is: mTitleText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.title);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting a View from the activity which will return null.. you need to create/inflate the view from the onCreateView..

click here and follow the steps on how to create and use a view from fragment..

[Click Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)

Comment: Thank you! This helped out a lot... I was able to get to the fragments! However I seemed to have run into some other problems afterwards, but they are unrelated to this question, so i will make another question